# In Java, how do you print out an anwer in a different literal?

Tags: java, integer, double, literals

I know that you add an L to a value if it exceeds the scope of an integer but you still have to print it as such. I understand the concept of doing it when you're just printing out a plain number.

What about when you're using a defined variable instad?

Say I have something like.

```
double a = 2.5;
System.out.println(a);
```

I want "a" to be printed out as a integer.

Thanks for any answers in advance :)

Comment: If you were to print it out as an integer, it would be rounded to the nearest whole number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.round` for instance.

```
System.out.println(Math.round(a));
```

or you can *format* it as an integer as follows:

```
System.out.printf("%.0f%n", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

cast double a to `Double` and use `a.intValue()`

```
Double a = new Double("2.5");
System.out.println(a.intValue());
```

Comment: Hmm all of these methods seem to work, the book I was using didn't mention any of them for some reason. I guess it expected me to ask this on stack overflow. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NumberFormat`. There are predefined formats available which you could use for your particular use-case.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
double a = 2.5;
System.out.println( format.format( a ) );
```

But it also allows to create one for more difficult output, like with a specified number of decimals. That would be much harder using `Math.round` or the other suggestions made here.